MAUI Toolbar Image won't stay centered
I'm working on a project using .Net Maui and I'm noticing something that is triggering my OCD. We want to have an image in the center of the toolbar throughout the whole app. I'm using the default for now. This is what the "home" page of the app looks like.

Here is what the other pages look like, when the back arrow is displayed

Looks like its off center for sure. Here is my code. I'm doing all the formatting with xaml.
Code:


<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Clicked="showTutorial">
        <ToolbarItem.IconImageSource>
                <FontImageSource
                Glyph="&#x3F;"
                Color="LightBlue"
                Size="20"/>
            </ToolbarItem.IconImageSource>
        </ToolbarItem>
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
<Shell.TitleView>
    <Image Source="dotnet_bot.png" 
           HeightRequest="35"
           WidthRequest="65"
           HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
           VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
           Aspect="AspectFit"
           />
</Shell.TitleView>



How can I force the image to stay centered in the toolbar?

The image is not centered because the back button takes up some space in the toolbar. If you set a background color for the TitleView, you may find the difference (actually the image is centered).
Without back button,

With back button,

The workaround is that you may customize your own back button,
For shell, you may first set the IsVisible to false,
<Shell.BackButtonBehavior>
    <BackButtonBehavior IsVisible="False"/>
</Shell.BackButtonBehavior>

Then you may design your TitleView. You may find an image for back button and add a tap gesture recognizer to the image,
<Shell.TitleView>
    <Grid BackgroundColor="Yellow" >
        <Image Source="backbutton.png" WidthRequest="30" HorizontalOptions="Start">
            <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"/>
            </Image.GestureRecognizers>
        </Image>
        
        <Image Source="dotnet_bot.png" 
           HeightRequest="35"
           WidthRequest="65"
           HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
           VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
           Aspect="AspectFit"
       />
    </Grid>
</Shell.TitleView>

To implement the event handler,
private void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, TappedEventArgs e)
{
    Shell.Current.GoToAsync("..");
}


That makes sense to me, I can't believe I didn't think of that thank you!

Glad it helps! Happy coding!
